# Java http servlet get data inside -d parameter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am sending a curl to a web app like

`culr -X POST 10.1.2.7?myname -d '&test=111'`

I am using parameter.getQueryString to get *myname*. I need to get that value in parameter **test**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this in your servlet:

```
 String test = request.getParameter("test");
```

Comment: Tried but getting null value

Comment: @Sharavanakumaar Murugesan Try to write your url in right format

Comment: My bad I didn't noticed where I used content-type as JSON